# PDFSharp merge with duplicate field names

Tags: c#, merge, duplicates, field, pdfsharp

I am using PDFSharp to programmatically fill out the fields of some existing PDF forms.  It's working great, however, I am running stuck on an issue where the PDFs I need to fill have duplicate field names.

FOR EXAMPLE, there is a "yes" and a "no" checkbox, and they both have the same field names.

This code has been working perfectly to access all other fields:

```
PdfCheckBoxField chkbox = (PdfCheckBoxField)(pdf.AcroForm.Fields["chkbox"]);
chkbox.Checked = true;
```

However, when BOTH checkboxes are named "chkbox", I get:

```
ArgumentNullException was unhandled
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: value
```

on the line:

```
chkbox.Checked = true;
```

Has anyone ever run into this before?  Is there any solution (BESIDES editing the PDF)?

Comment: are you trying to merge already existing pdf file?

Comment: sorry i think i misunderstood.Do you have a problem while filling a pdf ? or during merging..

Comment: My problem is with filling it.  Since there are two fields in the existing PDF with the SAME name, I get an error when trying to access them by their name.  I need to know how to differentiate between and access both fields.